# Problem plotting an image's Fourier transforms. "ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2592,) and (2592, 1, 3)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to get the fft of an image and then plot the fraq of that fft with using matplotlib. However, this error message:

> "ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2592,) and (2592, 1, 3)".

I tried to reshape my np.array like so:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fft2, fftshift

resim = Image.open(r'yeni.jpg')

resim_data = np.asarray(resim)

fourier = fft2(resim_data)

#psd2D = np.abs(fourier)**2


plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(abs(fourier).astype(np.uint8))
plt.title('fourier transform fraq')
plt.show()
```

*ERROR MESSAGE BLELOW:*

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "myfrouier.py", line 21, in
>
> plt.semilogy(abs(fourier).astype(np.uint8))   File
>
> "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>
> line 2878, in semilogy
>       return gca().semilogy(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py",
>   line 1844, in semilogy
>       l = self.plot(*args, **kwargs) 
>     File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py",
>   line 1810, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py",
>   line 1611, in plot
>       for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>    File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 393, in _grab_next_args
>       yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
>      File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 370, in _plot_args
>       x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y) 
>     File "/home/aybarsyildiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 234, in _xy_from_xy
>       "shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
>    ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2592,) and (2592, 1, 3)

Comment: The error seems quite clear. The shape of `y` is `(2592, 1, 3)`, you need a 2-D array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have the necessary 2d-array, but an array with an additional third dimension. You have to choose what you want to do with that dimension:

- If you only need the information of one channel, you can choose to keep only the n-th values of the third dimension:

  ```
  n = 1
  resim_data = resim_data[:, :, n]
  ```
- Calculate the mean for all values of the third dimension

  ```
  resim_data = resim_data.mean(axis=-1)
  ```
- Choose the maximum value for all values of the third dimension

  ```
  resim_data = resim_data.max(axis=-1)
  ```
- ...

---

**Example:**

I used your code with an example image with 244x244 pixels and got a similar error to yours:

> ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (244,) and (244, 244, 4)

I was only interested in the first channel, so I dropped all other unnecessary values from the third dimension:

```
resim_data = np.asarray(resim)
print(resim_data.shape)
n = 0
resim_data = resim_data[:, :, n]
print(resim_data.shape)
```

Which prints:

```
(244, 244, 4)
(244, 244)
```

As you can see, `resim_data` has no third dimension any more. No errors after that.